# Finding the stationary point of a multivariate function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

For $f (x) := 2x^4_1 + 2x_1x_2+ 2x_1 + (1 + x_2)^2$
what are the stationary points?

$\nabla f(x,y) = \langle f_{x_1}(x_1x_2), f_{x_2}(x_1x_2) \rangle $

$\nabla f(x,y) = \langle 2(4x_1^3 + x_2 + 1), 2(x_1+x_2+1)\rangle $

The only obvious critical point which jumps out is $x_1 = -x_2 - 1$

Have I made a mistake somewhere in my computations? I don't see a way to find the critical points.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** $4x_1^3=-1-x_2=x_1 \to x_1(1-4x_1^2) = 0 \to x_1(1-2x_1)(1+2x_1) = 0$

Comment: I'm sorry for the stupid question, but how have you equated
$$x_1(1-4x^2_1) =0 $$

(Nevermind, $4x_1^3 = x_1$) !

Just to confirm, we then have crit points at 
$x_1 = +- \frac{1}{2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{-3}{2} , \frac{-1}{2}$ ? (with correct coordinates ofcourse)

Comment: and also at $x_1 =0, x_2 =-1$